# Yii Cache Method Recording

Tags: caching, yii

I've just started working in Yii and I'm trying to add some functionality to the CClientScript, before beginning overwriting I'm trying to understand everything it's doing so I don't trip myself up later by not including something or including it wrong.

I've spotted a method call when registering scripts/files:

```
$this->recordCachingAction('clientScript','registerScriptFile',$params);
```

I've followed this chain down through a few classes to COutputCache in one case and seen the replayActions function. What is this used for? Is there any thing that requires this or is it as my suspicions and it's just a useful debugging feature to track caching?

Tl;Dr:
Why are caching actions recorded for later replaying?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Johnatan's answer is a correct and a good description of *what* it does. But I got a more detailed insight (which is more what I was looking for) into *how* it does it here:

[YiiFramework.com Forum Topic](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/24657-cache-action-recording/page__gopid__119654#entry119654)

Answer (score 1):

This method saves the output of cached methods. In your example the resulting output of `CClientScript->registerScriptFile()` will be cached (if caching is enabled, obviously) and saved for later calls. Later, if cache is still valid and `CClientScript->registerScriptFile()` is called again (with same parameters) the output won't be generated again, but taken from the cache.

Basically this is modular cache based on methods (most of methods affecting output are cached). Of course you can use it in your models, controllers and etc.

Comment: So when caching is enabled the cache is consulted for every function call? And what's the use in this function being used in a method that has no output? or am I misunderstanding what it's caching?

Comment: It's caching the result, not necessarily data send to the stdout.